# Passing property type as parameter

Tags: swift, closures

Is there a way to pass the property to a function as a parameter ?

```
class Car {

    let doors : Int = 4
    let price : Int = 1000
}
```

Is there a way to pass the Car property as a type to a function ?

I would like to achieve the following:

```
func f1(car: Car, property: SomeType) {

    println(car.property)

}

let c1 = Car()

f1(c1, doors)
f1(c1, price)
```

Would **closures** help, if so how ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you want, but using closure:

```
func f1<T>(car: Car, getter: Car -> T) {
    println(getter(car))
}

let c1 = Car()

f1(c1, {$0.doors})
f1(c1, {$0.price})
```

Comment: Awesome !! Just a little confused what $0 represents. Wouldn't $0 represent the first argument in the closure ? In this case the closure takes only one argument which is the getter. Could you pls explain

Comment: `getter` is a closure `Car -> T`. It receives `Car` instance and returns something `T`. In this case, `$0` is a instance of `Car`.

Comment: Thanks a ton !!! pretty neat !! Just for my understanding it is the same as `func f1<T>(car: Car, getter: (Car) -> T)` . Just writing `(Car)` within parentheses . You are spot on since `Car` is the only argument, so parentheses is not required

Comment: Yes, with or without parentheses is OK if it accept only one argument.

Answer (score 5):

As Bill Chan said, nowadays we would use [keypaths](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/expressions/#Key-Path-Expression):

```swift
func f1<Value>(car: Car, keyPath: KeyPath<Car, Value>) {
    print(car[keyPath: keyPath])
}

f1(car: car, keyPath: \.doors)
```

My original answer, using `NSObject` types, is below. But this key path approach is generally preferable, as it gives us compile-time validation of the key.

---

Back in the day, one would have used Objective-C key-value coding by subclassing from `NSObject`:

```swift
class Car: NSObject {
    @objc let doors: Int = 4
    @objc let price: Int = 1000
}
```

Then, the `f1` function could be:

```swift
func f1(car: Car, key: String) {
    guard let value = car.value(forKey: key) else { return }
    print(value)
}

f1(car: car, key: "doors")
```

Comment: Thanks Rob, I was wondering if there was a way to achieve it through closures or without inheriting from NSObject ?

Comment: Conveniently, the object I was using inherited from `NSObject`, so this solution was exactly what I needed.

Comment: @user1046037 – Nowadays, we’d use [Key-Path expression](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/expressions/#Key-Path-Expression), which eliminates the need to subclass `NSObject`. See revised answer.

Answer (score 2):

Solution with key path:

```
class Car {

    let doors : Int = 4
    let price : Int = 1000
}

func f1<T: CustomStringConvertible>(car: Car, property: KeyPath<Car, T>) {

    print(car[keyPath: property])

}

let c1 = Car()

f1(car: c1, property: \.doors)
f1(car: c1, property: \.price)
```

Comment: Nice one, would be even better when you make the function generic type T which conforms to CustomStringConvertible