# Passing a getter as a function argument in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, closures

I have a custom data structure that I'd like to be able to use in a generic way. Specifically, I'd like to pass a getter as an argument, so I can run a particular function on a numeric property. This is the basic pattern I'm following (toy problem):

```
/** A getter for a numeric property of a generic type. */
func genericGet<E, T where T: NumberConvertible>(object: E, getter: E -> T) -> T {
    return getter(object)
}

struct EV : Linkable, Equatable, Comparable {
    var pitch: Int
    var ts: Double
    var dur: Double
}

let anEvent = EV(pitch: 61, ts: 2.55, dur: 1.0)

func  getSomethingFromSomething<E, T: NumberConvertible>(thing: E, getThing: E -> T) -> T {
    return myGet(thing, getter: getThing)
}

let somePitch = getSomethingFromSomething(anEvent, getThing: {$0.pitch})
print("pitch = \(somePitch)") // prints "61"
```

Fantastic! However when I try the same approach in my generic struct:

```
struct MultiLink<E where E: Linkable, E: Equatable, E: Comparable> {
    var item: E
    var linkedItems: [E]?

    func bestTransition<E, T: NumberConvertible>(getter: E -> T, scaling: Double) -> E? {

        if let items = linkedItems {
            let c = items.count

            for i in 0..<c {
                let linkedItem = items[i]
                let itemProp = genericGet(item, getter: getter) // <--- sadness!

                /** Yes, this is unfinished... */
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    init(item: E, linkedItems: [E]?) {
        self.item = item
        self.linkedItems = linkedItems
    }
}
```

the compiler complains:

```
Spliqs.playground:86:57: error: cannot convert value of type 'E -> T' to expected argument type '_ -> _'
            let itemProp = genericGet(item, getter: getter)
```

Thinking that maybe I was just going overboard by passing the "getter" through to another "getter", I also tried:

```
let itemProp = getter(item)
```

Seems reasonable (since E -> T is a getter signature), but I got a bizarre error:

```
Playground execution failed: Spliqs.playground:70:32: error: cannot invoke 'getter' with an argument list of type '(E)'
            let itemProp = getter(item)
                           ^
Spliqs.playground:70:32: note: expected an argument list of type '(E)'
            let itemProp = getter(item)
```

I say "bizarre" because it's telling me it how it "can't" invoke the getter, then also telling me I need to invoke it in exactly that way(???).  Am I doing something stupid that I'm just not seeing?

Comment: Just to clarify, btw, the basic approach comes from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28944271/passing-property-type-as-parameter/28944642#28944642

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quincey Morris, over on the Apple dev forums spotted the problem. By specifying E again on the bestTransition function, I effectively created **another** E. That's what produced the confusing error. Removing that made the posted code work.